# Kendo: Retrieve sorted list from local storage

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am having issues with rendering HTML from local storage using the `<script type="text/x-kendo-template"`

Basically, I am using kendo sortable list to allow a user to reorder a list of items if they so wish. This list is populated from Umbraco so content can vary.

So what I have is that if a user comes in to the website for the first time there will be no entries in the local storage so the list will be displayed in its default order (the order that the data is stored in Umbraco).

If a user changes the order it fires an event and saves the 'new' list order in the local storage and the list should be re-rendered on the page in that order. From that point forwards the order will be based on what is in the local storage, unless it gets cleared.

I have got to the point where by the order of items is stored in local storage but I am having difficulty in re-displaying this list on the page.

I'm sure it is something obvious but I can no longer see the wood for the trees.

Thanks, H.

example:

```
     var items = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>(DictionaryAliases.ITEMS);
        if (items != null && items .Any())
        {
            <div id="maincontent">

    <script id="tmp" type="text/x-kendo-template">
         <div id="sortable" class="widget">
              #= data#
         </div>
    </script>


            @{foreach (var i in items)
             { 
                     var tileTitle = i.GetPropertyValue<string> DictionaryAliases.ITEMS_NAME, String.Empty);
                     @displayItmes(i);
             }
             }
             </div>
        }



 @(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
            .For("#maincontent")
            .Cursor("url('" + Url.Content("~/content/web/sortable/grabbing.cur") + "'), default")
            .HintHandler("hint")
            .PlaceholderHandler("placeholder")
            .Events(events => events
                 .Change("onChange"))
        )

........................

        @helper displayItems(IPublishedContent Section)
        {

        var t = Section.GetPropertyValue<string>(title, String.Empty);
        var i = Section.GetPropertyValue<string>(ICON, String.Empty);
        int il= Section.GetPropertyValue<int>(ILINK, 0);
        var iId = Section.GetPropertyValue(ICON, -1);
        var url = strin.Empty;
        url = Umbraco.NiceUrl(@il);

        <div class="widget"  id="sortable" header="@t" href="@url">
            @t
            <div class="widget-image" header="@t" href="@url">
                 <img src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia(iId).Url" 
                     alt="=@Umbraco.TypedMedia(iId).Name" title="@t" header="@t" 
                     href="@url" class="tile-icon"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
```

This is the script:

```
<script>
var localStorageSupport = (('localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null));
    var data;
    var html;

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var matches = [];
    var searchEles = document.getElementById("maincontent").children;
    for (var i = 0; i < searchEles.length; i++) {
        if (searchEles[i].id === 'sortable' ){
                matches.push($(searchEles[i]).html());
        }
    }

 if (localStorageSupport) {
        data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("sData")) || matches;
    } else {
        alert("your browser does not support local storage");
        data = matches;
    }

    html = kendo.render(kendo.template($("#tmp").html()), data);
    $(".sortable").html(html);

})

function onChange(e) {
      if ((e.action === "receive") || (e.action === "sort") ){
        var item = data.splice(e.oldIndex-1, 1)[0];
        data.splice(e.newIndex-1, 0, item);
        localStorage.setItem("sData", kendo.stringify(data));
    }           
};

</script>
```

Sample data from local storage:

```
"\n            Driving test Doc\n            <div class=\"widget-image\" header=\"Driving test Doc\" href=\"file://C:\\Driving.pdf\">\n                    <img src=\"/media/1031/test-manual.png\" alt=\"=test-manual.png\" title=\"Driving test Doc\" header=\"Driving test Doc\" href=\"file:///C:\\Driving.pdf\" class=\"t-icon\">\n            </div>

\n    ","\n            Car kit\n            <div class=\"widget-image\" header=\"Car kit\" href=\"http://0.0.0.0/index.xxx?id=xx\">\n                    <img src=\"/media/1024/CatKit.png\" alt=\"=CarKit.png\" title=\"Equiom Toolkit\" header=\"Car kit\" href=\"http://0.0.0.0/index.xxx?id=xx\" class=\"t-icon\">\n            </div>
\n    "]
```

Comment: First, you should not have more than one id in the DOM, `id="sortable"` is repeating; Second, you should not store the whole element content in the localStorage, try to store an id or an index of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have now been able to resolve my issue, thanks to the guys at Telerik!

Here is a demo of the code that was provided to resolve my question.
http://dojo.telerik.com/ixono/7

Cheers,
H